# Convert HTML page to PDF without using itextsharp.dll in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf, pdf-conversion

I am using asp.net with C#. I want to convert my html page to pdf. But I don't want to use "itextsharp.dll" for the same.

I went to lot of Google and sites. I am looking for some free one.

Comment: iTextsharp is free one, why you don't want?

Comment: If it's so urgent, you could at least check your heading for typos

Comment: You might want to explain what you mean by *free*. You **are** free to use iTextSharp as long as you adhere to the AGPL. Other "free" libraries require you to adhere to probably other license types, e.g. GPL, LGPL, MPL, ... There hardly will be a good library without explicit license. Thus, please state which license types are ok for you.

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such inbuilt functionality available in asp.net by default. You have to use any third party dll for this one. I would advice to take a look on the PDFSharp library

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PdfSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/). It's an open source library that easily creates PDF documents from any .NET language.